# How can I get an average of times in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I Have a column of cells in excel of format hh:mm (The day is NOT included) like:

```
19:08
19:08
19:40
20:10

1:45 (Any Times before 12:00 noon are considered NEXT DAY)
```

one (or more of these) is after midnight.

The Average of these times is = **20:46**

But Excel AVERAGE gives **15:58**

I would like to calculate this average without adding extra columns or using VBA
Just one formula at the end of the column.
By the way, I also need to exclude any blank entries in the column for the calculations.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You'll need an averageif, I think - what do you want to average? Noon to noon like 11:59am is the **latest**?

Comment: correct Raystafarian ... Wouldn't AVERAGEIF just exclude entries less than 12:00? rather than adding 24 hours and including them?

Comment: Well since you want to skew the timeline, it will be trickier, I thought you wanted to exclude some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A5>=0.5,A1:A5,1+A1:A5))
```

Confirm as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

To exclude blank cells -

```
=AVERAGE(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A5)),IF(A1:A5>=0.5,A1:A5,1+A1:A5),""))
```

Comment: Seems to work. Is there a way to exclude blank entries in the column? Or is that asking too much of the formula?

Comment: @Flashheart I edited my answer to account for blanks.